# how to change global variable by className on Sass

Tags: css, sass

I'm using Sass (.scss) for my current project. 
Following example:

**SCSS**

```css
$ratioW : calc(100% / 1080);

@mixin ratio($width){
  $ratioW : calc(#{$width} / 1080) !global;
}

.column-1 {
  @include ratio(100vw);
}
.column-2 {
  @include ratio(50vw);
}
.column-3 {
  @include ratio(33.33vw);
}
.column-4 {
  @include ratio(25vw);
}
.column-5 {
  @include ratio(20vw);
}

.section-category {
  .section-in {
    position: relative;
    $margin-top-content : calc( #{$ratioW} * 240);
    $margin-top-content-half : calc( #{$margin-top-content} * 0.5);
    width:100%; height:100%;
    padding-top: $margin-top-content;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    // padding-top: $margin-
  }
}
```

body has single class column1~5. it added by javaScript. but $ratioW only 20vw. how to change it by className?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe your solution would be flexbox? :)

Comment: i just want to change global variable value $ratioW.

so it's flexbox. there are 5 doms. 
i swapped body class name by javascript when check box on dat.GUI.

body class="column-1" >
  .section-category { $ratioW == 100vw / 1080 }
body class="column-2"
  .section-category { $ratioW == 50vw / 1080 }
body class="column-3"
  .section-category { $ratioW == 33.33vw / 1080 }

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want 5 different values for a property to be applied depending of a class on `body`? You can use a `@for` loop for that, along with parent selector `&`.

Sass documentation:

- [**@for**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_10)
- [Referencing **Parent** Selectors: **&**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)

```css
$ratioW: calc(100% / 1080);
$nbCol: 5;

.section-category {
  .section-in {
    position: relative;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    @for $i from 1 through $nbCol {
      .column-#{$i} & {
        $margin-top-content: calc( #{$ratioW} / #{$i} * 240);
        $margin-top-content-half: calc( #{$margin-top-content} * 0.5);
        padding-top: $margin-top-content;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

edit: [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com) is a Sass playground where you can copy-paste my snippet and see the compiled CSS (*à la Codepen*).

Output is:

```
.section-category .section-in {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column-1 .section-category .section-in {
  padding-top: calc( calc(100% / 1080) / 1 * 240);
}
.column-2 .section-category .section-in {
  padding-top: calc( calc(100% / 1080) / 2 * 240);
}
.column-3 .section-category .section-in {
  padding-top: calc( calc(100% / 1080) / 3 * 240);
}
.column-4 .section-category .section-in {
  padding-top: calc( calc(100% / 1080) / 4 * 240);
}
.column-5 .section-category .section-in {
  padding-top: calc( calc(100% / 1080) / 5 * 240);
}
```